# Retrieving HTML content from a page requiring authentication using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to prototype a PHP script which can extract data from an HTML page. So far it works fine with html pages which don't require authentication. But how can I retrieve content from a page which requires a user to log in first?

Below is my current code:

```
<?php
 $url="http://anandtech.com";
 $html = file_get_contents($url);
 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 @$doc->loadHTML($html);
 $xml=simplexml_import_dom($doc);
 $items = $xml->xpath("/html/body/section[@class='content']/section[@class='main_cont']/div[@class='pipeline']/div[@class='pipeline_cont']/ul[1]/li[@class='hide_resp']/a[1]/span[text()]");
 echo '<ul>';
 foreach ($items as $item) {
   echo '<li>' . $item . '</li>';
 }
 echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: what is the output you are getting now?

Comment: Just so you know, said username and password are easily intercepted over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean HTTP autentification you can user curl_init()

```
  $ch = curl_init();    // initialize curl handle
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); // set url to post to
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4); // times out after 4s
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $port);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:password'); // add POST fields
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

or you can post get/post values via

```
  $ch = curl_init();    // initialize curl handle
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); // set url to post to
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4); // times out after 4s
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $port);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'login='.$username); // add POST fields
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

see [curl_setopt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)